# What exactly does 'Bytes per row' mean in SQL Server max. capacity specifications

Tags: sql-server

See [Max Capacity Specs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143432.aspx)

So next to 'Bytes per row' it is 8060 but then later next to 'Characters per ntext or nvarchar(max) column' there is 2^31-1.

Max columns is 30,000.

I do not understand how there can only be 8060 bytes in 1 row when eg the other 2 numbers (2^31-1 and 30,000) are so huge.

Well I'll have a go at what I think may be the explanation.
Sure I can define 30,000 nvarchar columns but say 29,999 must be null if one of them contains a string of length roughly 7500.

And if I want to have some data in the other 29,999 columns I need to use row-overflow storage which would cripple the possibility of fast searches.

(Pleeease let's not get into a discussion of the type "why would you need 30,000 columns, you need to normalize etc". My numbers are just to illustrate my possible complete misunderstanding of the 8,060 Bytes per row limit.)

Comment: Please read the additional information in your link, it answers your query and as mentioned in the additional information please read: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186981(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks Steve. I understand now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Rows` are stored in `Pages`, page size is 8KB after deduction of space required to store system information you have 8060 bytes for data. Row size restriction means row cannot be split over several pages. `Text` and obsolete `Image` types are stored in pages of special type outside of "normal" 8KB pages. Long strings that overflow regular page's size are moved to pages of another special type *row overflow storage* as you mentioned. Original `row` which is still stored in "normal" data page retains only keys to make it possible to access those outer pages with long data.

Check out this calculation algorithm for table size estimation:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178085.aspx

Comment: Thanks Ivan but I am still very confused and the following note in your link adds to my confusion. Essentially it says that the 8060 limit can be exceed no problem.

"You can combine varchar, nvarchar, varbinary, or sql_variant columns that cause the total defined table width to exceed 8,060 bytes. The length of each one of these columns must still fall within the limit of 8,000 bytes for a varchar, varbinary, or sql_variant column, and 4,000 bytes for nvarchar columns. However, their combined widths may exceed the 8,060 byte limit in a table. "

Comment: Key word is **var_** - this means 0-[defined max size]. Possible size starts from zero which allows you to create several `varchar(8000)` columns - because it does not explicitly require 8000 bytes for each value in every row. Actual space needed is determined when some data shows up. If and when the actual data in those **var_** columns exceeds available space of regular 8K page - it is moved outside to _row overflow storage_.

Comment: Thanks Ivan - I understand now.