# Understanding documentation of "Row-Overflow Data Exceeding 8 KB"

Tags: sql-server

The SQL Server Documentation on [Storage and Row Size](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms186981(v=sql.105)) limit of 8060 Bytes says

> The length of individual columns must still fall within the limit of 8,000 bytes for varchar, nvarchar, varbinary, sql_variant, and CLR user-defined type columns. Only their combined lengths can exceed the 8,060-byte row limit of a table.

Please someone explain and help me understand:

1. "length of individual columns must still fall.." - Is the Length referred here is represented by LEN() OR DATALENGTH()?
2. How can be the largest size allowed by VARCHAR(MAX) be less than 8060 Bytes?
3. "Only their combined lengths can exceed" - does it mean sum of Sizes of all VARCHAR(MAX) columns in the table, even if filled to the full of DataType capacity, are allowed without Error - "Msg 511 Cannot create a row of size XXXX which is greater than the allowable maximum of 8060".

Answer (score 1):

The length restriction must refer to the data length, and not the actual text length.  For different encodings, two strings of the same length may have a different size.

For `VARCHAR` and the other types mentioned (*not* including `NVARCHAR(MAX)`), each column is limited to 8060 bytes, but the sum of several such columns may still exceed 8060 bytes.

Regarding the apparent contradiction for `NVARCHAR(MAX)`, the [link you gave](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/sql/sql-server-2008-r2/ms186981(v=sql.105)) goes on to add a note:

> This restriction does not apply to varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), text, image, or xml columns. For more information about the storage of these columns, see Using Large-Value Data Types, Using text and image Data, and Using XML Data.

Comment: Oh, so the first reference to VARCHAR implied VARCHAR(X) with X as a definite number but the reference to VARCHAR in the note you mentioned meant VARCHAR(MAX) with MAX size limited by DataType size limit. If yes, yes X can be utmost 8000/4000 based on whether it is VAR or NVAR. If yes to all this, then that is an incomprehensible, stupid documentation. If not, my comprehensive skills are bad. Nevertheless, Thanks ! I can't upvote your explanation since my reputation numbers doesn't entitle me to.

Comment: some more explanation found @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35405490/what-exactly-does-bytes-per-row-mean-in-sql-server-max-capacity-specification?rq=1